# why is progress bar not updated when the main UI is running by using backgroundworker? c#.net

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, progress-bar

Can anyone enlighten me on this?
It's updated until the main UI thread is completed, why is that so?

Part of my code:

//Initialize the BW

```
 private void InitializeBW()
        {
            BW.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            BW.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            BW.DoWork +=
                 new DoWorkEventHandler(BW_DoWork);
            BW.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            BW_RunWorkerCompleted);
            BW.ProgressChanged +=
                new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
            BW_ProgressChanged);

        }
```

\Do Work event

```
 private void BW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        for (int i = CurrentProcess; i <= Process; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                worker.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
        CurrentProcess = Process;
    }
```

\Update main UI

```
 private void BW_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lbProgress.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
            pgBar.Refresh();
            lbProgress.Refresh();
        }
```

\My main UI Operation

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DatabaseParam DBPara = new DatabaseParam();
                isCreate = true;
                EDFields(!isCreate);

                DBPara.ServerName = txtServerName.Text;
                DBPara.DatabaseName = "PARKS_ARCHIVE_" + nudYear.Value.ToString();
                DBPara.ID = txtUserName.Text;
                DBPara.Password = txtPassword.Text;
                DBPara.DataFileName = "PARKS_ARCHIVE_DATA_" + nudYear.Value.ToString();
                DBPara.DataPathName = txtPath.Text + "\\PARKS_ARCHIVE_DATA_" + nudYear.Value.ToString();
                DBPara.DataFileSize = "10MB";
                DBPara.DataFileGrowth = "1024MB";
                DBPara.LogFileName = "PARKS_ARCHIVE_LOG_" + nudYear.Value.ToString();
                DBPara.LogPathName = txtPath.Text + "\\PARKS_ARCHIVE_LOG_" + nudYear.Value.ToString();
                DBPara.LogFileSize = "10MB";
                DBPara.LogFileGrowth = "20MB";

                CreateDatabase(DBPara);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("ucArchivePurge", "btnCreate_Click", ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

//Call to create database and table

```
private void CreateDatabase(DatabaseParam DBParam)
    {
        try
        {
            Process = 7;
            BW = new BackgroundWorker();
            InitializeBW();
            if (BW.IsBusy != true)
            {
                // Start the asynchronous operation.
                BW.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
            txtProgress.Text = "Creating " + DBParam.DatabaseName + "...";


        SQLConn.Open();
        myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, SQLConn);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLConn.Close();
        BW.CancelAsync();

        Process = 14;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblAuditLogin...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();

        SQLCreate.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = SQLCreate;
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateAuditLogin;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        BW.CancelAsync();

        Process = 21;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblAuditTrail...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();               
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateAuditTrail;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        BW.CancelAsync();

        Process = 28;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblCardType...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateCardType;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 35;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblErrorLog...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateErrorLog;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 42;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblKanban_Card...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTableKanban;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 49;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblModule_Master...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTableModule;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 56;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblMTV...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTableMTV;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 63;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblPickList_Detail...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTablePickDetail;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 70;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblPickList_Header...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreatePickHeader;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 77;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblProd_Requisition...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTableProduction;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 84;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblUser_Master...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTableUser;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Process = 91;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Creating Table tblUser_Rights...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        myCommand.CommandText = CreateTableRight;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLCreate.Close();

        Process = 100;
        BW = new BackgroundWorker();
        InitializeBW();
        if (BW.IsBusy != true)
        {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            BW.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        txtProgress.Text = "Updating Log File...";
        txtProgress.Refresh();
        myCommand.CommandText = Log;
        myCommand.Connection = SQLConn;
        SQLConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLConn.Close();
        if (MessageBox.Show("Database " + DBParam.DatabaseName + " has been successfully created !", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtProgress.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Create Database",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (SQLConn != null)
            SQLConn.Close();
        if (SQLCreate != null)
            SQLCreate.Close();
        isCreate = false;
        EDFields(!isCreate);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help? Urgent!
Any reply will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like most of your logic is on the UI thread itself instead of in the background thread.  Basically, your UI is waiting (or sleeping) until the database is created before it can update.

The BW_DoWork should call other methods.  It's essentially a wrapper for all the work you need to do off of the main UI thread.  In your code, you have it reversed where methods are calling the worker.

Comment: So, you are saying that I need to call CreateDatabase inside BW_DoWork?

Comment: @Roy.hpr Yes, it makes no sense to do your work in the UI thread where it can freeze your application. The Background Workers sole purpose is to do the work and report back to your UI the Progress.

Comment: Is it possible to implement continuals growing progress bar in this way?

Comment: Here is what I would do: (1) change btnCreate_Click to initialize the background worker [personally, I would initialize the worker somewhere other than in the code behind, but I'm keeping this simple], and call it with RunWorkerAsync, (2) rewrite BW_DoWork to call CreateDatabase, (3) at key points in CreateDatabase, check for cancel, (4) within CreateDatabase, call BW.ReportProgress() with the percentage you would like to report.  You can pass the background worker, as a parameter, to CreateDatabase.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap all of the work in to a single background worker that creates the database.  You could kick of a sequence of methods for the steps of the create database method and check the result of each one to determine if you should cancel.  As each step (or method) succeeds, you can report progress back on the callback event (BW_ProgressChanged).  In the progress changed event handler you want to update the txtProgress control there.  If you start setting properties on UI controls in a background thread you will start running in to cross-threading issues.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Start the BackgroundWorker.
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
        // Wait 100 milliseconds.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        // Report progress.
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        // Set the text.
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
    }
}
```

The BackgroundWorker object is the traditional way to do this with WinForms, but have you had a look at [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx)?  The Task is .net 4.0 framework specific so it may not apply depending on the version of the framework you are targeting.

Comment: Yup, but what i want is a continuals growing progress bar. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes.  In the BW_ProgressChanged accumulate a value to assign to the progress bar or let each step define a percent complete and send report that back on the BW_ProgressChanged.  I added an example to my answer.  If it is helpful please mark as answered.  Thanks.